# Ninja Forms API - Can't update field value using ninja_forms_submit_data filter

Tags: wordpress, forms, filter, ninja-forms

I'm using this code to loop through the fields:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', function ( $form_data ) {

    $form_model = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_data[ 'id' ] );

    foreach( $form_data[ 'fields' ] as $field ){
        $field_model = $form_model->get_field( $field[ 'id' ] );
        $field_key = $field_model->get_setting( 'key' );
        if( 'subject_test' == $field_key ){
            $field_model->update_settings( 'value', 'foo' )->save();
        }
    }

    return $form_data;
} );
```

subject_test is the key of the field I'd like to change the value.

I've tried many other ways to change the value but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone point me out in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
$form_data[ 'fields' ][ $field_id ][ 'value' ] = 'foo';
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed answer, your question refers to the key being used, but your answer is only using the ID... What have you changed? And how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

@Lee Here is the full function I used:

```
// Change email_admin based on subject using a hidden field
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', function ( $form_data ) {
    $form_model = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_data[ 'id' ] );
    foreach( $form_data[ 'fields' ] as $field ) { // Loop through fields
        $field_model = $form_model->get_field( $field[ 'id' ] );
        $field_key = $field_model->get_setting( 'key' );
        $field_id = $field[ 'id' ];
        if( 'subject_value' == $field_key ) {
            $subject_value = '';
            $subject_value = $form_data[ 'fields' ][ $field_id ][ 'value' ]; // Take subject dropdown value.
            $email_redirect = get_string_between($subject_value, '{', '}'); // Get email from subject value.
            $new_subject = delete_all_between($subject_value, '{', '}'); // Remove {email} from subject value.
            $form_data[ 'fields' ][ $field_id ][ 'value' ] = $new_subject; // Assign new subject value.
        } elseif ( 'subject_send' == $field_key ) {
            if ( isset($email_redirect) )
                $form_data[ 'fields' ][ $field_id ][ 'value' ] = $email_redirect; // Give hidden field the email which is used in send to field.
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $form_data;
} );
```